# Python - Using external libraries for a cross-system script

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing a Python script that will be used by multiple people on different OS's and I'm trying to figure out the best way to include a third-party package so that users don't have to install the package themselves before running the script. The particular library I'm using is the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package. It works great for me when I install it via pip, but when I download the source and try to import it from my project root, it doesn't work. I either get "Attempted relative import in non-package" or "No module named MyProject.request" depending on how I try to import it.

So I suppose my first question is, am I even approaching this right? I've never written a python script for more users than just myself, so I've never been concerned with issues like package installation. Is the correct approach to include the source for the Requests library and import it relative to my project, or is there an easier approach?

As a follow-up question, if I am on the right track, what's the proper procedure for including this package in my project? Right now my file structure looks like this:

```
MyProject/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    requests/
        requests/
            __init__.py
            [bunch of other stuff]
        [other files/folders]
```

In main.py I've tried `from .MyProject.requests import requests` and `from .requests import requests`, and both give me "Attempted relative import in non-package." I haven't messed around with sys.path yet, but I've seen mixed advice as to whether that's the "right" way to do it. My primary concern is getting this script to run on user machines without them having to do anything besides run it. I don't want users to have to install an external package, but I can't seem to get it working by trying to import the source.

Comment: Have you tried removing on `requests` subdirectory? I think `MyProject/requests/requests/[bunch of stuff]` is too much; try `MyProject/requests/[bunch of stuff]`.

Comment: Actually, what is happening, is that you're trying to import the "outer" requests directory, which is not a package (as it doesn't have an `__init__.py` file. Hence removing one layer of subdirectories may solve your problem.

Comment: Yep, seems like that was the problem. I wasn't sure exactly how the requests package works, so I didn't know if any of the files in the "outer" directory were important to the actual package, but it looks like they're not.

Comment: As for 'how the requests package works': from a quick glance at the code, all imports inside the package are relative. Which is why this works in the first place. If there was any absolute import (`import requests.x` or `from requests import x`), you would not be able to put the requests package inside another package. So keep in min that this trick may not work for every package.

Answer (score 0):

Per Evert's response, my problems seems to have been the multiple "requests" directories. When I moved the sub-directory up and eliminated the superfluous files/directories from the Requests source it worked perfectly.